# Which Memory is Overflown?

Tags: c++

```
#include<cstdlib>
long int val=10000;
int main()
{
for(;;val++)
{
malloc(val);
}
return 0;
}
```

This above code will generate an error **Segmentation Error**
In this case which memory is overflowing and why?

Comment: "Overflow" is something a spacecraft does to a planet. Your program is simply running out of memory. It keeps allocating and leaking memory until there's none left.

Comment: as written it should not segfault, you should just loop forever

Comment: @IgorTandetnik or a drain

Comment: @pm100 Actually, I meant "overfly" (overflew, overflown). So I thoroughly botched that joke.

Comment: What happens when the `long int` overflows? Odds are good val goes negative and the program tries to `malloc` negative storage. The memory manager HATES that. Seems this isn't a problem. `malloc` takes a `size_t`, so it's still positive. Neat.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - i got yr joke and was making another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop:

```
for(;;val++)
{
  malloc(val);
}
```

never exits.  It will keep allocating buffers of increasing size indefinitely... That is until `val` wraps around and becomes negative, then it enters undefined behavior territory, which may trigger a segfault.

Buffers allocated with `malloc()` need to be freed with `free()` at some time. So, you need to store the value returned by `malloc()` so you can later pass the buffer to `free()`.  Since this was tagged C++, you should consider something like this instead:

```
#include <vector>

long int val=10000;
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    v.emplace_back(std::vector<int>(10000));
  }
  // hopefully your app does need 4 MB of integer data, it can use them from here on...
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks to @IgorTandetnik and @pm100 who helped me clarify this answer.

Comment: *"will keep on allocating 10000 bytes buffers"* Actually, buffers of ever increasing size.

Comment: val will keep incrementing, so it allocating more memory every time. eventually malloc will start failing. Then val will wrap round to a negative value and all sorts of fun will ensue

Comment: Formally incorrect. `val` might become negative, but `size_t(val)` does not. This does not trigger Undefined Behavior, `size_t` has well-defined wrap-around behavior. The UB is actually before that: `long int` is signed, and does **not** have well-defined wrap-around behavior. Hence, you can't count on `val++` becoming negative.